# AWSAccessKeyId not authorized

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I am attempting to use a GET request to use the Amazon Mechanical Turk [GetFileUploadURL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_GetFileUploadURLOperation.html) function. However, I get this error code when attempting it.

```
AWS.NotAuthorized The identity contained in the request is not authorized to use this AWSAccessKeyId
```

This is the code I'm using to create the request.

```
    now = DateTime.now

    #For creating the signature hash
    data = "AWSMechanicalTurkRequesterGetFileUploadURL" + now.to_s
    sha256 = OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256.new
    sig = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(sha256, Rails.configuration.secret_key, data)
    signature = Base64.encode64(sig)
    puts "https://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com", "/?Service=AWSMechanicalTurkRequester&AWSAccessKeyId=#{Rails.configuration.aws_key}&Version=2014-08-15&Operation=GetFileUploadURL&Signature=#{sig}&Timestamp=#{now}&AssignmentId=#{mturk_results[0][:AssignmentId]}&QuestionIdentifier=file1"

    puts "\n\n"

    uri = URI('https://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com')
    params = {:Service=>"AWSMechanicalTurkRequester", :AWSAccessKeyId=>Rails.configuration.aws_key, :Version=>"2014-08-15", :Operation=>"GetFileUPloadURL", :Signature=>sig, :Timestamp=>now, :AssignmentId=>mturk_results[0][:AssignmentId], :QuestionIdentifier=>"file1"}
    uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(params)
    res = 0
    Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port,
        :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https') do |http|
        request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri

        res = http.request request # Net::HTTPResponse object
    end
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why not use the official Ruby SDK from Amazon or maybe rturk? Regardless, MTurk is very picky about date formatting, so I would assume that's the issue.

Comment: I was unable to find any functions in the Ruby SDK for getting file results back. I do get an UploadedFileKey from getHITResults, which contains part of a URL to be appended on to a base, but I've been unable to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to format your TimeStamp correctly. The time stamp must be in UTC and in the following ISO 8601 format: 
YYYYMMDD'T'HHMMSS'Z'. For example, 20150830T123600Z is a valid time stamp. Do not include milliseconds in the time stamp.

It needs to be of the form:
Timestamp=2016-04-23T08:00:05Z

While Ruby's DateTime.now method returns them of the form:
2016-08-05T10:43:27-07:00

You can read more about Timestamp and AWS signatures here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-date-handling.html

Comment: Another tip to consider, I'd use a super simple method while you work out the kinks in your AWS call signing. GetAccountBalance is a good candidate. More on that here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_GetAccountBalanceOperation.html